# Kubernetes Ingress service can not load static files

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have created ingress for some services on minikube (1.8.0):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
        path: /ui
```

When I access MINIKUBE_IP/ui, the static files of dashboard not work. Below are errors:

```
192.168.99.100/:1 GET https://192.168.99.100/ui/static/vendor.4f4b705f.css net::ERR_ABORTED
192.168.99.100/:5 GET https://192.168.99.100/ui/static/app.8a6b8127.js net::ERR_ABORTED
VM1524:1 GET https://192.168.99.100/ui/api/v1/thirdpartyresource 404 ()
...
```

Please help me to fix this error, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
You can solve it by defining new paths in the Ingress resource.

```
 rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ui
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
```

The "/*" will allow you to access the static files.

Other resources:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/333
- https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2238

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to annotation:
`ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"`
solves this problem.

If you use `- path: /*`, everything will populate under `/`. And connect directly to `http://<host_ip>` will end up getting the same as `http://<host_ip>/ui`, which is probably not ideal result.