# Rails app deploying with unicorn and Nginx can't load static resources on Kubernetes infraestructure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, kubernetes, unicorn, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy a Rails application using Kubernetes ... the main container of my application is built using ruby ​​2.5.5 + unicorn ... I used Mongo as DB ... the container works well because I tested the orchestration using docker-compose .... so ... I have a Deployment  file and a Service file (Cluster-IP type) for my services and an Ingress file to access the application ... but when the service is ready, The web application can not load statistical resources ... I'm trying many variants to solve this problem, but nothing work ... the alternatives that I test are:

- Change ingress file configuration [Kubernetes Ingress service can not load static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394686/kubernetes-ingress-service-can-not-load-static-files)

  - Add `- path: /*`
  - Add `ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"`
- Change Image build https://engineering.adwerx.com/rails-on-kubernetes-8cd4940eacbe

  - Construct image with rails + unicorn + nginx
  - Construct Image with rails + passenger + nginx

Configuration files:

- appX-deployment.yml https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IKC62g5OADpsZ-l9v9yuBvSJRlYwpLrb
- appX-cluster-ip-service.yml https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IKC62g5OADpsZ-l9v9yuBvSJRlYwpLrb
- ingress-service.yml https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IKC62g5OADpsZ-l9v9yuBvSJRlYwpLrb

Comment: I can't open your config files. Please just add them inline of the question. This is also better for future in case the external links go away. Also, please include information about the application (`Dockerfile`, Rails config, and unicorn config).

Comment: What's the path URL for your static files? are those different from the main URL?

Comment: this is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/cenit-io/cenit/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: Please edit the question and put all needed information there.